# Convergence of the following improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to study the convergence of $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^p-x^q}$

I noticed I could assume $p>q$, and I saw that in order for it to converge it must be $q<1$.

I am not able to study the convergence when $x$ is near $1$.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

When $x\to 1$, we have :
$$x^p = 1  + p(x-1)+\mathcal O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$
Therefore :
$$x^p - x^q = (p-q) (x-1)+\mathcal O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$

Therefore, $\frac{1}{x^p -x^q}$ is not integrable near $1$.

Comment: So integral is always divergent?

Comment: Yes, it is always divergent as a Riemann or Lebesgue integral. If you take the limit at $0$ and $1$ simultaneously, there might be a way for the divergences to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

As was observed in the first answer, the main problem is at $1.$ I prefer to explain that as follows, assuming for example $p>q$
$${1\over x^p-x^q}={1\over x^q}{1-x\over 1-x^{p-q}}{1\over 1-x}$$
The first two fractions have a limit (equal $(p-q)^{-1}$), when $x\to 1^{-}.$ Therefore the behaviour of the integral $\int\limits_{1/2}^1 (x^p-x^q)^{-1}\,dx$ is equivalent to the behaviour of $\int\limits_{1/2}^1 (1-x)^{-1}\,dx$ which is divergent.